# Iterar una lista en Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Tengo un modelo llamado `Precompra` y de allí me interesa por ahora el precio para calcular el total.
Que problema tiene este código que no me esta mostrando el resultado en la plantilla.

Este código lo programé en la `view.py` :

```
def precio_pactado(request):
    aux = 0
    precompra=list(Precompra.objects.all())
    for compras in precompra:
        aux = compras.precio + compras.precio
    return render(request, 'carrito.html', locals())
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Podrías mostrar como estableciste el atributo `precio` en tu models.py?

Comment: Roberto , podrías añadir el código de tu `template`  además de tu modelo `Precompra`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un error lógico al realizar la suma en el `for` ya que el valor de la variable `aux` **`siempre será el doble del ultimo elemento`** , la modificación sería simple , realizar la suma a la variable `aux` ,además no es necesario convertir a `Lista` para poder iterar.

```
def precio_pactado(request):
    aux = 0
    precompra=Precompra.objects.all()
    for compras in precompra:
        aux +=compras.precio
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
```

Para luego en la plantilla Imprimir dicho valor con `{{ aux }}`

Adicional sugerir hacer la suma directamente sin iterar los elementos. usando [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Sum
totaldos =  Precompra.objects.aggregate(Sum('precio')).values()[0]
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, sin embargo, no entiendo de que sirve convertir el QuerySet en una lista, no seria más fácil dejar `precompra=Precompra.objects.all()` y listo?

Comment: @Genarito No hace falta , error mio al copiar el código y no darme cuenta de ese detalle.

Comment: No me funciona ninguna de las dos formas

Comment: Esta es la plantilla: